# CSS Problem with <ul> element not expanding to size of list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, overflow

I was hoping someone could help me out with a navigation bar I'm styling in CSS. I'm having trouble with the ul element, it's not expanding to the size of the list - not too sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've set up a little prototype here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JCraine/NvKzM/2/

The offending UL element is in red. I'd be so grateful if someone could take a quick look for me!

Just scroll down to **header nav .submenu ul**  in the CSS to see what's going on

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are floating your listitems which causes the parent not to know how high it should be.

Comment: Do the .submenu child list items inherit the float property?

Comment: No, your selector does: header nav ul li

Answer (score -1):

floating the `<li>` elements sometimes causes the `<ul>` to collapse, a simple solution is to float both the `<li>` and the `<ul>` and place the `<ul>` inside a container.